# How to replace string front back in python

Tags: python

Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

```
front_back('code') → 'eodc'
front_back('a') → 'a'
front_back('ab') → 'ba'
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: @Chris: No, OP just wants to swap the first character with the last one, leaving the middle intact. It is not a duplicate (though it _is_ trivial, and it should be possible to reverse-engineer the link to answer just this subproblem). OP, please state what you have tried, and what specific obstacle have you encountered in performing your task, since this should be basic Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
def front_back(s):
     if len(s) < 2:
         return s
     return s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0]
```

output:

```
>>> front_back('a')
'a'
>>> front_back('ab')
'ba'
>>> front_back('code')
'eodc'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using index swapping:

```
a = 'code'
b = list(a)
b[0], b[-1] = b[-1], b[0]
print(''.join(b))
```

If the string might be empty, use:

```
a = 'code'
if a:
    b = list(a)
    b[0], b[-1] = b[-1], b[0]
    print(''.join(b))
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might have been because this gives an error for the empty string.

Comment: I tested and it worked for all the three cases given (learned string manipulation from it, it is a good answer).

Comment: @kaya3 Edited mine

Answer (score 1):

Here we are

```
def front_back(val):
    if len(val) <= 1:
        return val

    return val[-1] + val[1:-1] + val[0]


print(front_back('code'))
print(front_back('a'))
print(front_back('ab'))
```

outputs

```
> python test.py
eodc
a
ba
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with slices:

```
def swapfirstlast(x):
   if len(x) == 1:
      return x
   else:
     return x[-1:] + x[1:-1] + x[:1]

In [3532]: swapfirstlast('a')                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[3532]: 'a'

In [3533]: swapfirstlast('code')                                                                                                                                                               
Out[3533]: 'eodc'

In [3534]: swapfirstlast('ab')                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[3534]: 'ba'
```

Comment: Try with `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

The first character of a string `s` is `s[0]`, and the last character is `s[-1]`. The characters in the middle are the slice in between: `s[1:-1]`. So we can build the string by joining those three parts in the right order:

```py
>>> s = 'code'
>>> s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0]
'eodc'
```

Note that this will give strange results for strings with one character, and fail completely for the empty string; you can write `if len(s) >= 2:` to check beforehand, and use `else:` to handle the too-short strings differently.

```py
def swap(s):
    if len(s) >= 2:
        return s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0]
    else:
        return s
```